# Jquery selectmenu - disable for mobile (use iOS selects)

Tags: android, jquery, ios, select

I'm using jquery-ui selectbox and want to disable it for mobile. I couldn't find an option like that in the docs.

Is there a way to have iOS / Android selects override the jquery-ui selectbox?

Answer (score 0):

There is no option to do so at the moment. You could try to add a switch by yourself and use this: https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui-extensions/tree/selectmenu